# how to insert Json object in database

Tags: java, php, mysql, arrays, json

i have a json object as like this type

```
[{"productName":"ddsf","productPrice":234234,"quantity":23}][{"productName":"ddsf","productPrice":234234,"quantity":23}]Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [productName] => ddsf
            [productPrice] => 234234
            [quantity] => 23
        )

)
```

how to insert this object array at a time. my database colum is id ,productname, productprice, quantity , so i want to insert at a time multiple row

Comment: Please try yourself and ask a more specific questions

Comment: Hint: create a `Product` object, set its properties using the json object that you have, then save it on the database. *Spending some effort researching* would tell you how to do these things.

Comment: Your tags include both Java and php... Downvoting for unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of database connection :

```
       //ENTER YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION INFO BELOW:
         $hostname="localhost";
         $database="dbname";
         $username="username";
         $password="password";

   //DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
     $link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
     mysql_select_db($database) or die('Could not select database');
```

Exemple of INSERT array in database :

```
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);

 //Database Connection
require_once 'db.php';

 /* insert data into DB */
    foreach($obj as $item) {
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database product`.`table name` (productName, productPrice, quantity) 
       VALUES ('".$item['productName']."', '".$item['productPrice']."', '".$item['quantity']."')");

     }
  //database connection close
    mysql_close($con);

   //}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PostgresSQL database which provides JSON type.
So you can directly insert JSON string into columns which is of type JSON.